# Rasa chatbot : My custom action is not active

Tags: python, rasa

I'm trying to use Rasa chatbot, but the custom action is not active. I first ran `rasa run actions`, and then ran `rasa shell` in another Anaconda Prompt. However, while chatting, the below error message came.

`2021-07-28 18:06:07 ERROR    rasa.core.actions.action  - Failed to run custom action 'action_check_userinfo'. Couldn't connect to the server at 'http://localhost:5055/webhook'. Is the server running? Error: Cannot connect to host localhost:5055 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5055)]       2021-07-28 18:06:07 ERROR    rasa.core.processor  - Encountered an exception while running action 'action_check_userinfo'. Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Please check the logs of your action server for more  information.`[Rasa shell error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKJCA.png)

And this is `rasa run actions` picture. I think that when I use the command, the action server should be working, but it seems to just stop immediately.[Rasa run actions error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Une7S.png)

Finally, this is my `endpoints.yml` code.

```
action_endpoint:
    url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the action server is alive by pinging `http://localhost:5055/webhook`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running on a server. Make sure to use rasa actions and rasa server on different servers. Because it won't run on the same command prompt simultaneously. 
Then too you want that to happen try using [tmux](https://linuxize.com/post/getting-started-with-tmux/) if you have any access to that server's command line.
If you have any doubts feel free to add them in the comments